# How to prevent newline at the end of html input field?

Tags: html

```
<form>Label<input type="text" size="10"></form>'More Stuff<br>
```

Produces:

[image]

How can I make "More Stuff" show on the same line as the input box, immediately after it:

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A <form> element is a [block element](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp).

You can use CSS to make text float around it:

```
 <form style="display:inline;"><label>Label <input/></label></form>
```

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
clita kasd gubergren, 
<form style="display:inline;"><label>Label <input/></label></form>
sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos
et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,
no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
```

Comment: Just noting here that, this works for `<input type='file' ...` also.

Comment: startingly, you can add display:inline to individual elements as well...

Answer (score 2):

Besides the fact the upper solutions did not work for me and if you also want to avoid using form, you could use display:flex.

this worked for me

```
<span style='display:flex;'>Label<input type="text" size="10">More Stuff</span>
```

Comment: This one worked for me as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`<form>` is a block level element by default (things go below it). You could say something like '`<form style='display:inline'>` and that would help. Or you could float them left like:

```
<form style='float:left'>Label <input type="text" size="10"></form>
<div style='float:left'>More stuff</div>
```

Comment: ditto!  Thanks!  The display:inline did it for me!

Comment: I'd give this a "check" too as answered, but apparently I can only give it to one answer??

Answer (score 1):

If `style = "display:inline;"` didn't work you need to check the next item (html tag), you might also need to add the same style to it.