# Copy textbox and surrounding text without newline

Tags: html, forms, input, newline

How can I prevent newline in a html form for copy and paste into notepad:
Similar to this question:
[How to prevent newline at the end of html input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748822/how-to-prevent-newline-at-the-end-of-html-input-field)

If I copy the text and paste it into notepad, the newlines are present.
The code snippet in first answer displays correctly on web page, but if I copy and paste into notepad, the newlines around the form input are present.
From code snippit:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, Label 
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa  <----- MY input into form. Text in form is on a new line.
 sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

I need an inline textbox, that when text around it as well as inside text box is copied and pasted it is on one line.

eg:
`grep " <form style="display:inline;"><input/></label></form>" s*-config`

Displays correctly on web page, but if I select all the text and paste it into notepad there are carriage returns:
output in notepad:

```
 grep " 
textbox data  
" s*-config
```

I want it to display as in notepad

```
  grep "textbox data" s*-config
```

UPDATE:
I sort have got it to do what I want with:

```
<strong style="display:inline;">grep "<span contenteditable></span>" s*-config</strong>
```

The "contenteditable" allows me to add data between the quotes and it copies and pastes without newlines. The problem now is that it is not clear that this an editable field. It needs either a boder around it and or some plaeholder text. (Placeholder doesn't seem to work)

Comment: Replace \n with ''.

Comment: The textbox itself has newlines around it. When I select text on either side as well as the contents of the textbox and paste this into notepad. I get newlines on either side of the textbox. There is no "\n" to remove